# Rounding to the closest 5 cents

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, rounding, qsqlquery

I have a requirement which says the amount value should be rounded to the nearest 5 cents to 2 decimal places.

```
 Example:
 255.263745  to 255.25  -- 26 taken to 25
 57.2115     to 57.20  -- 21 taken to 20
 100.75586   to 100.75
```

I have tried below ways, but I could not get desired output.

```
select (RIGHT('00000000'+LEFT( CAST(CAST( ISNULL(198.85,0)*ISNULL(128.370,0) AS DECIMAL( 15,0)) AS VARCHAR( 15 )), 8 ), 8 ))

select CEILING(((ISNULL(198.85,0) * (ISNULL(128.370,0)/100)))/.05) *.05
```

Working sample:

```
SELECT REPLACE(FORMAT(CAST(ROUND(((ISNULL(198.85,0) * (ISNULL(128.370,0)/100)/05)),2)*05 AS DECIMAL(10,2)),'000000.00'),'.','') AS [Actual Amount]
```

OutPut: 00025525

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
round(mycol / 5, 2) * 5
```

Or if you really want to be strict about the output datatype:

```
cast(round(mycol / 5, 2) * 5 as decimal(10,2))
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=95b4fe142c7ae3265f7e6eb7ee1b21be)**:

```
select mycol, cast(round(mycol / 5, 2) * 5 as decimal(10,2)) res
from ( values (255.263745), (57.2115), (100.75586) ) t(mycol)
```

```
mycol      | res   
:--------- | :-----
255.263745 | 255.25
57.211500  | 57.20 
100.755860 | 100.75
```